# How to sum the values of an aggregated query

Tags: apex, batch, map, aggregateresult, count

I have a parent object Account with related contacts these related contacts have (several) related statuses i.e. A B C. These are all the statuses a contact has had.

On the parent Account I need to store the total amount per statuses of all the related contacts.

So on the account I would have

```
Status__A = 10
Status__B = 33
```

Im trying to resolve this with a batch proces but are stuck that I would need a loop in a loop.

I also tried using the aggregated result which gives met the count per contact per status but then I dont have the AccountId to relate them to.

```
SELECT Contact.id, status__r.name status, COUNT(Id) recordCount
                          FROM Statuses__c
                          WHERE  Contact.Accountid IN :Accounts 
                          GROUP BY Contact.id, status__r.name
```

How would I resolve this in a bulkified way ?

Comment: Just to confirm , each contact can have more than 1 statuses?

Comment: @Rohit Yes each contact can have more statuses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the account-level aggregates, query by that, instead:

```
  SELECT Contact.AccountId AccountId, status__r.name status, COUNT(Id) recordCount
  FROM Statusses__c
  WHERE  Contact.id IN :Accounts 
  GROUP BY Contact.AccountId, status__r.name
```

If `Accounts` is a list of Accounts, then use `WHERE Contact.AccountId = :Accounts` instead.

Comment: The "WHERE Contact.AccountId" was miscopied I updated that in the question. I already tried that but that gives me a weard result. I get only one result back, 1 account id with one status with a count. 0000x00000Xxxx0XXX, 1.0, 95. I do see total 17 rows or does the query editor in the anonymouse window not show you all the rows?

Comment: Thanks!. Its seems that the Query Editor only shows the last recod in this case. After your comment I realized the recordcount was 17. After doing Object status = groupedResults[0].get('status'); I realized this. You saved my day Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas The totalSize property in the API is the number of records involved, but there was only one row because of the grouping. That's why the query editor looked weird.